# SSL in node.js express server running but not working

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl

What I have is a Commodo Positive SSL SHA-2 Certificate for a domain sat *webadd.in*

I have three files that have been provided to me by http://namecheap.com

```
webadd_in.crt
webadd_in.p7b
webadd_in.ca-bundle
```

my main.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var https          =         require("https");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var config     = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ssl.key/webadd_in.in.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ssl.crt/webadd_in.ca-bundle') //insert the the .ca-bundle file here
};
var port = 443;
app.set('port', port);

require('./routes')(app);
var server = https.createServer(config, app).listen(port, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

My code runs but there is no output whatsoever. no errors no warnings nothing at all.
it works if i remove ssl part and change the port

I have apache on this server but I have a2dismod ssl and port 443 is free indeed

Also I would like to know if I can run this node server on a port other than 443 so that I can access it like this https://webadd.in:3030/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if you end up being in the situation like this here are the possible reasons and solutions.

**Note: To keep formatting correct, I have placed links and commands in the end.**

1. If you are trying to use the given ca-bundle file dont. Create a cert chain. Ask for the file from Authorities.
2. If you are 100% sure that the *.key and *.crt are correct files, their formatting is incorrect. [namecheap provided me with corrected format].
3. To run the certificate (certificate can be single domain) on different ports you need to use nginx reverse proxy. You can then use node.js and php and any other thing. It is also a very good method as you get only the best of both.

**I was getting stuck because of some formatting error in the chain certificate which was resolved by extra removing spaces.**

Some Commands and Resources

1. You may check if the certificate matches CSR or Private key here
   https://www.sslchecker.com/matcher
2. Command to create chain certificate `cat domain.crt COMODO_DV_SHA-256_bundle.crt >> domain_cert_chain.crt`
3. nginx config file should be like this.

> notes: 
>      create a index.html file (can be blank) in node.js directory.
>      configure apache to run on port 8080 on localhost only
>      configure node to run on port 3030 on localhost only
>      restart apache node and nginx
>      nginx reverse proxy guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache
>
> ```
> server {
>   listen   80;
>         listen 443;
>         ssl off;
>         server_name domain.in;
>         ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_bundle.crt;
>         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_in.key;
>         root /var/www/html/;
>         index index.php index.html index.htm;
>         server_name domain.in;
>         location / {
>           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
>   }
>   location ~ \.php$ {
>           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
>       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
>       proxy_set_header Host $host;
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
>   }
>         location ~ /\.ht {
>           deny all;
>   }
> }
> server {
>         listen 3035;
>         listen 443;
>         ssl on;
>         server_name domain.in;
>         ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx_bundle.crt;
>         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_in.key;
>         root /var/www/domainnodeapi/;
>         index index.html index.htm;
>         access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
>         error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.lo;
>         client_max_body_size 10G;
>         location / {
>             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>             proxy_buffering off;
>        }
>  }
> ```

4. command to restart nginx, apache

> sudo nginx -s reload
>      sudo service nginx restart
>      sudo service apache restart
>      
>      use pm2 for node

if you get error

> nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt") failed (SSL:)

it is because of the file in the bracket. check formatting error.

If you get openssl error/ version unknown/ file not found:

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge openssl libssl-dev
> sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
> ```

Hope this helps you in some way.